# Invoke multiple sql using powershell in sequence with runtime arguments

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to run sql queries in sequence. If any one of the sql query fails, then the windows powershell script should exit and send email. The log should be written to the log directory. where data= < this will passed in the run time>

Example code below:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT data from emp where data=<run time argument>;" -ServerInstance "MyComputer\MyInstance"  

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT data from class where data=<run time argument>;" -ServerInstance "MyComputer\MyInstance"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT data from stud where data=<run time argument>;" -ServerInstance "MyComputer\MyInstance"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT data from cust where data=<run time argument>;" -ServerInstance "MyComputer\MyInstance"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT data from new where data=<run time argument>;" -ServerInstance "MyComputer\MyInstance"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you gathered any information on the different parts you need to bring together (SQL, email, writing to a file)?

Comment: Script has to execute sql queries in sequence. Store the output of the sql query in file naming like file1, file2 etc. The where condition input will be passed during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

What does it look like when "sql query fails"? You could rely on the Invoke-SqlCmd function's return, or have an expected "fail" message (or multiple messages).

I'm not familiar with Invoke-SqlCmd. Check out [the MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/cc281720.aspx); `-AbortOnError` looks like it would be helpful to you, as would `-ErrorLevel`.

Here is an outline for a single expected error, with comment on how to extend. it's worth storing your queries in an array so that you can loop over then and break out of a loop instead of having linear code (where you have to copy and paste the check part after each `invoke-sqlcmd`

```
# string with a single error. you could use an array and add
# a foreach ($error in $errors) on the line marked #here
$expectedError = "Failed"

# Functions have to appear above where they are used
Function Check-SQLResults($result){

    # a try-catch statement will execute the code in the try part, going
    # to the catach part on a TERMINATING error
    try{
        # check each line for your expected error
        foreach($line in $result){
            #here
            if($line -like "*$expectedError*"){
                Write-Error "Something went wrong: $line" -ErrorAction Stop
            }
        }

        # true is only returned if none of the result lines are like your error
        return $true
    }catch{

        # false is returned if any lines contain error
        return $false
    }
}

# store the sql outcome in a variable so you can check it
$result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT data from emp where data=;" -ServerInstance "MyComputer\MyInstance"

# using a function that tells you if the results contain an error or not is neater.
# again, this is manually dealing with errors and invoke-sqlcmd provides other options.
$resultIsErrorFree = Check-SQLResults -result $result

If(resultIsErrorFree -eq $true){
    # execute next invoke-sqlcmd
}else{
    # Send e-mail. $results can be added to body.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm very new to powershell.                                                                                                      `$SqlQuery =  "select * from emp where data=<runtime>"
try
{
$SqlResourceMon = Invoke-SqlCmd -Query $SqlQuery -ServerInstance "SQLINSTANCENAME" -Database "temp" -ErrorAction Stop -verbose 4>&1 | outfile someoutfile.txt
}
catch 
{
$_ 
Send-MailMessage -From "X" -To "Y" -Subject "Test email" -Body "TEST"
"error running sql $SqlQuery"
}`    Please check if this will work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, welcome to PowerShell! MSDN and the documentation are your best friends. The code looks fine as far as I can see; have you tried to run it? I'm not able to run it for you.